# How to replace some characters in a string

Tags: c#

What is the best way to replace \n or \r or \r\n when they are between double quotes, with an empty string

using c#?

Example: "abc\ndef" should be "abcdef"

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried `String.Replace`? Define "best" What do the double quotes have to do with anything? Are there newlines outside of double quotes that shouldn't be replaced?

Comment: Yes, newline inside the quotes need to be replaced and outside of double quotes need to be kept as is

Comment: so, if I have "abc\ndef"\n"ghi\n" I want to get "abcdef"\n"ghi"

Comment: Edit your question with a better problem definition and what you've tried so far. Look at regular expressions.

Comment: I am new to regex: I tried 
            string input = "abc\ndef"\n;
            string replacement = " ";
            string pattern = @"[\r\n]+(?=[^“”]*”)";
            Regex rgx1 = new Regex(pattern);
            input = rgx1.Replace(input, replacement);
            string pattern = @"[\n]+(?=[^“”]*”)";
            Regex rgx2 = new Regex(pattern);
            input = rgx2.Replace(input, replacement);
            pattern = @"[\r]+(?=[^“”]*”)";
            Regex rgx3 = new Regex(pattern);
            input = rgx3.Replace(input, replacement);

But it replaces all \n from the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public static String RemoveQuots(String source) {
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
    return source;

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(source.Length);

  Boolean inQuot = false;

  foreach (var ch in source) {
    if (ch == '"')
      inQuot = !inQuot;

    if (!inQuot || ((ch != '\n') && (ch != '\r')))
      sb.Append(ch);
  }

  return sb.ToString();
}

...

String source = "\"abc\ndef\"";
String result = RemoveQuots(source);
```

Elaborated test

```
   String source = "preserved: \n \"deleted: \n\" \"\" preserved: \n tail";
   // preserved: 
   // "deleted: " "" preserved: 
   // tail
   String result = RemoveQuots(source);
```

Explanation:

```
   1st \n is out double quots
   2nd \n is within double quotes: \"deleted: \n\" (note \")
   3d  \"\" is just empty "" *string* so \n is once again doomed to be deleted
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its the "best", but this will work:

```
  string a = "abc\nefg";

  a = string.Concat(a.Split(new char[] { '\n', '\r' }));
```

Can you define what you mean by Best ? Fastest ? Less Code ? Readable ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [string.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string b = "abc\ndef";

b = string.Replace("\n", "");
```

**Output:**

```
b = "abcdef"
```